# Deprecation warning for writing pandas Dataframe to csv in python 3.3

Tags: python, pandas

A python 3.3 specific question:

I'm getting a Deprecation warning when writing a pandas Dataframe to csv in python 3.3 (doesn't happen in python 2.x).

```
>>> df2 = DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5))

>>> df2.to_csv("test.csv")
/nfs/tools/lib/python/3.3/current/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py:1190: DeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future
values = values[:, slicer]
/nfs/tools/lib/python/3.3/current/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py:624: DeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future
result = arr_idx[key]
```

The resulting csv file seems to be okay.  Is this something to be concerned about?  Will the pandas package be updated to reflect this?

Thanks

Comment: what version pandas,numpy ?

Comment: numpy 1.8.1, pandas 0.13.1

Comment: I believe this warning is from numpy starting in 1.8.1 (and not suppressed by pandas); this is all fixed in master/0.14 (though I cannot reproduce using the same version pandas/numpy as you), odd.